# Performance of different If statement versions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm just curious.. how does the performance differ between the different versions of conditional statements?

Namely:

```
if ( x == false) //doSomething

if ( x === false ) //doSomething

if ( !x ) //doSomething

!x && //doSomething
```

Personally, I would prefer using the 3rd one since it is a lot shorter than the other three. But I am a bit skeptic to whether I am unaware of a "possible" performance drawback. Even if it is just a difference of milliseconds, it matters for me.

Thanks!

Comment: You are aware that there are functional differences, yes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Comment: "how does the performance differ" — In which version of which JavaScript runtime? These things change as different optimisations are added.

Comment: @PrasathK wow thanks! I never knew about the difference of == and ===. Well anyway, I think the question is still answerable since i'm looking for performance difference. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @AJNaidas it's ok ...

Comment: downvotes even though I got to learn something and a particular friend learned something from this post as well. Thanks @Ramunas for the performance-related answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These four variations have different semantics and/or syntactic constraints.

```
if ( x == false) //doSomething
if ( !x ) //doSomething
```

These two are equivalent and will `doSomething` if `x` is any "falsy" value — `false`, `0`, `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, or the empty string. I doubt that after parsing there will be any performance difference at all.

```
if ( x === false) //doSomething
```

This will `doSomething` only if `x` is exactly `false`. If `x` is any other "falsy" value (or any "truthy" value) then `doSomething` will not execute. There may be a slight performance gain because no type conversion takes place.

```
!x && //doSomething
```

This is more or less equivalent to the first two, but `doSomething` is restricted to be an expression. I would expect performance to be like the first two.

Comment: this answered my question. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

I will not dive into functional differences between statements as Ted already did this but you can always check your JS performance at http://www.jsperf.com

Here is yours: http://jsperf.com/ifperf

Comment: That only tests the performance when `x` is `false`. A better test would include the effects of `x` being other values (including `undefined` and `NaN`). Also, I've found jsperf to be unreliable for such microbenchmarking.

Comment: Yeah, sure. No offence to OP, but I think he did not know of such site/web tool and therefore asked a question here. Now he can test whatever he wants to: `undefined`, `NaN`, `0`, `1`, `{}`, `null` etc. And a question was about performance

Comment: Yep. It would also be better to initialize `x` in the setup code, rather than timing both the assignment and the `if` test.